# createVector() a partir de imagen

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy haciendo un código en p5.js en javascript y me gustaría saber si existe alguna manera de subir (upload) una imagen y crear vectores (con createVector) donde haya un punto negro en la imagen subida.

Espero que haya alguna manera porque estoy buscando por internet y no encuentro nada.

Comment: puedes explicar un poco mas porfavor

Comment: Quiero una funcion / algoritmo que haga un createVector() donde haya color negro en una imagen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUCIONADO

Haciendo un loadPixels() puedo saber si los colores RGBA son 50 o menos, para crear un vector en su posición:

```js
var img;
function preload() {
  img = loadImage('assets/imagen.jpg');
}
function setup() {
  image(img, 0, 0);
}

function mousePressed() {
  img.loadPixels();
  for (var i = 0; i < pixels.length; i += 4) {
       if (pixels[i] <= 50 && pixels[i+1] <= 50 && pixels[i+2] <= 50) {
     console.log(createVector((i/4) % width, (i/4) / width)));
       }
  }
  img.updatePixels();
}
```